# Getting an error in removing word just before the colon in R

Tags: r, regex

I have the below dataframe

```
head(df)

index   song              year  artist  genre   lyrics
    2    Till i am gone    2010    Eminem   Rap   Chorus:It's too much, it's too tough
```

i have done other data cleanups such as converting everything into lower case using gsub and removing words between brackets, however, not finding the syntax to just remove the word and the colon that is after it, for example in my row, i want to remove "chorus:"

After the syntax it should be

```
lyrics
It's too much, it's too tough
```

The following code will delete everything before the colon which i don't want as this colon can be anywhere in the cell

```
gsub(".*:","",foo)
```

Comment: Is there a reason you couldn't post the actual output of `head(df)` or — as the SO R FAQ suggests — a `dput()` of it? Also, it's not clear what you have and what you want. There doesn't seem to be a before/after.

Comment: the lyrics are huge for each song so i just pasted a line. Not sure if that answered the question. i will edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify to only remove the word immediately before the colon. 
I expanded your test set to show that it works.

```
foo = c("Chorus:It's too much, it's too tough ",
    "ABC Chorus:It's too much, it's too tough ")

gsub("\\w+:", "", foo)
[1] "It's too much, it's too tough "  "ABC It's too much, it's too tough "
```